# Emacs two windows for one file, seamless scrolling?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to open one file in two windows, that are next to each other (C-x 3) and the first window shows lines x .. y and the next window has lines y .. z *and* when you scroll one window the lines in the other window should adjust automatically?

Answer (score 10):

Emacs does this nicely. You want [follow-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html).